# EF: How to get "Grade" entity for "Student" having GradeId=1

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have below database  structure with data,

[image]

And below are `entity` and `dbContext` classes,

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SchoolDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}

public class Grade
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } = new HashSet<Student>();
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to get `Grade` entity for `Student` having GradeId=1. How to pass GradeId?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var gradeId = 1;

        var context = new SchoolContext();
        var data = context.Grades.Include(x => x.Students.Where(how to pass gradeId here)).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `var data = context.Grades.Include(x => x.Students.Where(y => y.GradeId == gradeId)).SingleOrDefault();` Otherwise why not do it from the other side of the relation? You could say `context.Students.Include(x => x.Grades).Where(x => x.GradeId == gradeId);` I guess that depends on what you're trying to achieve though.

Comment: `y => y.GradeId` giving compile error, as `GradeId` is NOT a property for `Student`

Comment: That should be because you haven't included `Grade` as a navigation property on `Student`. You could add `public Grade Grade {get;set;}` to your Student entity to enable that

Comment: agree, but I can't add this in my real production code :(

Comment: I'm inclined to ask why? Adding that navigation property is just the reverse of the relation that already exists by the fact that you've got the student collection on the Grade. All it's doing is basically telling Ef that it's there.

Comment: Otherwise I think you might have to do it in two queries instead of using include. Unless Somedusts' answer does what you want?

Comment: how to do that using 2 queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are in fact trying to get Grade with Id equals to 1 and pre-load related data. So you can try something along these lines:

```
var data = context.Grades.Include(x => x.Students).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
var data = context.Grades  
   .Join(context.Students.Where(s => s.GradeId == 1),
      g => g.Id,        
      s => s.GradeId,  
      (g, s) => new { Id = s.Id, GradeName = g.GradeName }).ToList();
```

Comment: `s => s.GradeId == 1` giving compile error, as `GradeId` is NOT a property for `Student`

Comment: @user584018 Yes, but you can consider adding the Grade navigation and GradeId property to the Student class